# Ubuntu CLI - run shell script with predefined arguments

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, shell

I have a shell script that prompts the user for manual input (eg. `1` & `enter`, `2` & `enter`, etc).
I would like to automate this process by passing pre-defined arguments to the script while when executing, is this possible? Eg . How does one go about this?

Example:

- Run script: `bash <(curl -s -L domain.com/myscript.sh)`
- Wait 1 second
- Enter `1` and `enter`
- wait 1 second
- Enter `2` and `enter`

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

If your bash function or a script takes a parameter, here's how to give
it a default value:

```
VAR=${1:-DEFAULTVALUE}
```

This assigns VAR the value of the first argument, using instead
DEFAULTVALUE if it's not specified. Note the colon and dash characters.

Here's an example of a function that starts a simple HTTP server that
serves from the current directory, with optional parameter for the port
to listen to, which defaults to 8000:

```
function server() {
    local port="${1:-8000}"
    python -m SimpleHTTPServer "$port"
}
```

[source](https://coderwall.com/p/s8n9qa/default-parameter-value-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe stdin of your command like this:

```bsh
echo '1\n2' | <command>
```